# How to use foursquare api in my app

Tags: iphone, mapkit, foursquare

I'm Making an App using MapKit, with a few POIs, could anyone tell me about some example or documentation which I can learn it with? I mean, using the venueID...
Thank you!

Comment: Details of what you've tried, where you've looked etc may help people find specific details for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution!

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/samples.html

Answer (score 0):

http://groups.google.com/group/foursquare-api/web/api-documentation

Hope this helps!